# Bluetooth sometimes works, sometimes doesn't work, per each Ubuntu system boot

Tags: bluetooth

After I installed Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth worked and I could pair my bluetooth peripherals and they worked. I booted into Ubuntu again and the bluetooth icon in the launcher starts flickering and my devices stopped working. I rebooted Ubuntu and bluetooth was working again. Next time I rebooted it stopped working. This problem happens repeatedly everytime I boot Ubuntu, sometimes bluetooth works, sometimes it stops. I tried to use the drivers from Additional Drivers but the problem persists. I did some research and tried these commands, but I don't know what to do now.

```
lshw -class network
description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: 24:0a:64:49:78:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:df400000-df407fff memory:df200000-df3fffff
```

and

```
lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0480:0110 Toshiba America Inc 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17cf ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04b4:0101 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Keyboard/Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0738:1705 Mad Catz, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.032076] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.057619] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.349413] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.349441] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.349445] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.349448] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.349453] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.469459] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    3.470452] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    3.486477] Bluetooth: hci0: NUNO
[    3.487455] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1469
[    3.487864] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.487865] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd not found
[    4.569598] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.569599] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.569602] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   34.098347] hid-generic 0005:046D:B01A.0005: input,hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Keyboard [MX Anywhere 2S] on 24:0A:64:39:1A:79
[   50.855727] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   50.855731] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   50.855734] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  498.150022] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  514.274031] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  530.146048] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

etc. it goes on like that.